# Hiding UITabBarController's tabBarItem while being able to show associated view nevertheless

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller, xcode9

I am trying to create a navigation for my iPhone "Tabbed App" which would consist of (obviously) `UITabBarController` and [`SWRevealViewController`](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for revealing side-menus.

All the views in my application **must have** both `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationBar` displayed, however, links which appear in left-side menu (handled by `SWRevealViewController`) **must not** appear in `UITabBarController`.

My left-side menu links are handled in this way:

```
import UIKit

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedIndex = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row + 1  // hardcoded for time being
        let tabBarController = revealViewController().frontViewController as! UITabBarController

        let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers![selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
        navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

        tabBarController.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(tabBarController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Now, I tried to remove a link for one of the views which I don't want to show in my `UITabBarController` as follows:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let index = 2  // hardcoded for time being
        viewControllers?.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

but if I click associated link in left-side menu now, I get an `NSRangeException index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]` error (of course, because I removed the particular `tabBarItem` from `UITabBarController`).

My question is: how can I "hide" the item from `UITabBarController` but still being able to reference it (and open it) from my side menu?

**UPDATE**
My storyboard at the moment looks like this:[image]

Comment: So... you have a tab bar controller with `A` `B` `C` tabs... current tab is `B`... you also have a menu listing `D` `E` `F` `G`... user taps `E` on the menu... What is supposed to happen? Current tab `B` is *replaced* by `E`? Or `A-B-C` tabs becomes `A-B-C-E`?

Comment: Let's say I have `A` `B` `C` `D` `E` views. I want to display `A` `B` `C` in my TabBar and `D` `E` in my side menu only. However, both `D` and `E` should have TabBar visible once opened. In my storyboard, all views are connected to my TabBar controller so that TabBar appears visible on them, maybe that is the wrong approach in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to use a "menu" to manipulate the Tabs - that's what Apple has designed the More... and Edit... features for.

Depending on your overall design / navigation / user experience flow, two reasonable options would be:

1. Instead of replacing the current selected Tab, `.present` a modal view controller, with a "Cancel" or "Save" or "Done" button to `.dismiss` it (whatever would be appropriate).
2. Since you state each Tab's ViewController is a NavigationController, you could `.push` the menu-selected view controller onto the current stack. Then your interface could use the standard "< Back" button navigation.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for clarifying!